# Customize After Facebook Login Screens

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have done logging through Facebook SDK in android and it was successful. Now, What I want is to create a custom login screen and on the press of submit it should send the request directly to Facebook server like the original Facebook app. I don't want to redirect to Facebook's generated login screen. You can say it is like developing our own Facebook app. **OR if creating custom login screen and sending request to Facebook server is not possible then after login customise Facebook login as screen and Facebook permissions screen.** The problem is I'm not getting any API to do this. Does any one knows how to do it..?

Comment: That is not possible. Facebook has no interest in letting you do that. Users benefit from the login dialog looking the same for every app - makes it easier for them to use, and helps prevent phishing.

Comment: Yeah i understand. Then after Facebook login screen, is it possible to customise at least Facebook permissions screen?

Comment: No, also not possible.